# how to extract a topic data from a text file using matlab?

Tags: matlab

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did the following

```
rostopic echo /topic_name > filename.txt
```

Then I got a text file the contains the data of the topic...

I want to save the data using matlab code in arrays

for example I have the following text file:

```
 secs: 4113
  nsecs: 565000000
  frame_id: ''
pose: 
  position: 
   x: 5.0
   y: 5.0
    z: 5.0
  orientation: 
    x: 0.0
    y: 0.0
    z: 0.0
        
    w: 0.0
 --- 
 header: 
  seq: 2544
  stamp: 
secs: 4113
nsecs: 590000000
  frame_id: ''
pose: 
  position: 
   x: 5.0
y: 5.0
  z: 5.0
 orientation: 
x: 0.0
   y: 0.0
   z: 0.0
    w: 0.0
---
```

I want to save the pose position.x = [ 5 2 ..... ]
same as for y and z.. I want to save the data in arrays using matlab ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/169586/how-to-extract-a-topic-data-from-a-text-file-using-matlab?/) by [RSA_kustar](https://answers.ros.org/users/18471/rsa_kustar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 275 on 2014-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this will help :
[http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/Matlab/textread.html](http://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Egermain/PPS/Topics/Matlab/textread.html)
For this i dont think ROS is required !

---

Originally posted by [Sudeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/9671/sudeep/) with karma: 460 on 2014-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1